# How to change the sql order value with select option using php and jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I need to change the ORDER value of an sql based on the chosen select option
I have an action.php where I fetch the values from the DB. I want to put a sort select option where the loop fetch values order can be change based on the selected option.

**action.php**

```
if (isset($_POST["fetchValue"])) {  

echo '
 form name="sort" id="sort" action="" method="post">
 <div class="form-group">
     <label for="sort_item">Sort by: </label>
     <select name="sort_item" id="sort_item" class="form-control">
     <option value="age">Date of birth</option>
     <option value="last_name">Last Name</option>
     </select>
 </div>
 </form>';

 $fieldNameMapping = array(
        'age'     => 'dob',
        'last_name' => 'user_lastname');

$sql = "SELECT * FROM test_field_tb tf
        INNER JOIN users u ON tf.user_id = u.user_id
        WHERE tf.user_id = 5
        ORDER BY '".$fieldNameMapping[$_POST['sort_item']]."' "; // need to change that value base on the selected option

$run_query = $conn->query($sql);

while ($row = $run_query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
...
 }
```

**JQuery - js file**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#sort_item").change(function() {
    //get the selected value
    var selectedValue = this.value;

    //make the ajax call
    $.ajax({
        url: 'action.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {sort_item : selectedValue},
        success: function(data) {
            //how to i change the sql value here
        }
    });
});


function getFetch(){
    $.ajax({
        url :   "action.php",
        method: "POST",
        data    :   {fetchValue:1},
        success :   function(data){
            $("#get_display").html(data);
        }
    })
}

});
```

**display.php**

```
<div id="get_display"></div>
```

**Getting error:** Undefined index: sort_display `$fieldNameMapping[$_POST['sort_item']]`

Comment: After `</form>';` put everything inside `if(isset($_POST['sort_item'])){..}`

Comment: do i also need to put my while loop inside it, cause now I am not getting of the fetch values

Comment: well using what u say, no value are being fetch at all

Answer (score 0):

The `ORDER BY` needs to be added conditionally

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM test_field_tb tf
        INNER JOIN users u ON tf.user_id = u.user_id
        WHERE tf.user_id = 5 ';
if (!empty($_POST['sort_item']))
        $sql .= "ORDER BY '".$fieldNameMapping[$_POST['sort_item']]."' ";
```

And in the `success` handler for the ajax call, populate the box like this:

```
success: function(data) {
        $('#get_display').html(data);
    }
```

Comment: Put a `var_dump($sql);` in there so you can see the query being built. Is the `ORDER BY` clause added?

Comment: `SELECT * FROM test_field_tb tf INNER JOIN users u ON tf.user_id = u.user_id WHERE tf.user_id = 5`, no `the ORDER BY` clause is present at all

Comment: Can you verify that the `$('#sort_item').change()` is firing? You could add `console.log(selectedValue)` to make sure it's grabbing what you expect. Also, if you're in Chrome you can use inspector to examine the AJAX call and make sure it looks right

Comment: That means the `.change()` function isn't being called. Instead of `$(document).ready(function(){})` try using just `$(function(){})` ... Also, since you're triggering everything with jQuery you don't need the `<form>` tag. It's just grabbing info from the single `<select>` element.

I have to retire for the evening, but good luck. You're on the trail of the problem now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163846/discussion-between-jonatha-flint-and-sorak).